# SQL Increment value depending on changes in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Similar to this : [T-SQL incrementing counter based on change in a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380595/t-sql-incrementing-counter-based-on-change-in-a-column-value)

I have this table :

```
ID  |  VALUE
5   |  A    
6   |  A    
6   |  A    
6   |  B    
6   |  A    
6   |  B    
6   |  B    
6   |  A    
6   |  C
```

The desired result is to have this :

```
ID  |  VALUE    | GROUP
5   |  A        | 1
6   |  A        | 2
6   |  A        | 2
6   |  B        | 3
6   |  A        | 4
6   |  B        | 4
6   |  B        | 4
6   |  A        | 5
6   |  C        | 6
```

A new column (GROUP) with a value that increments everytime the first two columns change, but doesn't increment when the first two columns values are the same as the previous line.

So far, with the RANK OVER() function, the best I can achieve is this :

```
ID  |  VALUE    | GROUP
5   |  A        | 1
6   |  A        | 2
6   |  A        | 2
6   |  B        | 3
6   |  A        | 2
6   |  B        | 3
6   |  B        | 3
6   |  A        | 1
6   |  C        | 4
```

Comment: SQL Server tables have no inherent ordering.  Please elaborate in your question how the ordering for the columns is specified.  You should also edit the question and include the query you used for the imperfect results.

Comment: How would you expect the optimizer to know `6,A` is after `6,B` and not after the other `6,A` ?? How do you decide the order?

Comment: The dataset is ordered as showed in the example from another timestamp column. First line is "oldest" timestamp, last line is the "newest" timestamp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a column called `ordering` that specifies the ordering of the records.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "natural" ordering to the rows.

You can do what you want with a difference of row numbers and then some additional manipulation:

```
select id, value, dense_rank() over (order by grp) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             min(ordering) over (partition by id, value, seqnum - seqnum_iv) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by ordering) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, value order by ordering) as seqnum_iv
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

The innermost subquery calculates to sequences of values.  I encourage you to look at the results to see what is happening.  The difference is constant for each of your "islands".

The second gets the minimum of the `ordering` value for each group.  This can then be used to assign a sequential value as the ultimate result.