# TSQL Window Function to split dataset into groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There must be a simple TSQL solution to this. I just don't know what it is.

I have a table that looks like this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | `1` |
| 4 | `1` |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | `1` |
| 7 | `1` |
| 8 | `1` |
| 9 | 0 |
| 10 | `1` |

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM dbo.Table ORDER BY Col1
```

As you can see, when you order the table by Col1 it produces groups of rows in Col2 of either 1s or 0s.

All I want to do is label the groups consecutively, 1,2,3, and so on, to produce the following:

| Col1 | Col2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | `1` | `2` |
| 4 | `1` | `2` |
| 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | `1` | `4` |
| 7 | `1` | `4` |
| 8 | `1` | `4` |
| 9 | 0 | 5 |
| 10 | `1` | `6` |

There must be a Windows function or something that does this. I've poured over Itzik Ben-Gan's book on it, googled it, and I just can't find a solution. I imagine it has something to do with ROW_NUMBER but I can't make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you'd like to play around with it, here is how you can produce the table:

```
    SELECT 
        Col1,Col2
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 1 Col1, 0 Col2
            UNION SELECT 2,0
            UNION SELECT 3,1
            UNION SELECT 4,1
            UNION SELECT 5,0
            UNION SELECT 6,1
            UNION SELECT 7,1
            UNION SELECT 8,1
            UNION SELECT 9,0
            UNION SELECT 10,1
        ) a
ORDER BY Col1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Increment value depending on changes in other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292723/sql-increment-value-depending-on-changes-in-other-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL incrementing counter based on change in a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380595/t-sql-incrementing-counter-based-on-change-in-a-column-value/29382442)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu unfortunately not directly, as its a slightly different problem. But it probably gets me closer.

Comment: Gordon's answer is literally an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382442/2029983) in one of the one's I linked to...

Comment: Oh! Sorry @Larnu! I read the problem in that link, and it was slightly different to mine, although as you say, that solution would have fixed both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select col1, col2,
       sum(case when prev_col2 = col2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by col1) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lag(col2) over (order by col1) as prev_col2
      from t
     ) t;
```