# Increment by one when value changes

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm unable to understand this part

this is the data

```
WITH data AS (
              SELECT 'person1' person, 'day1' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day2' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day3' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day4' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day5' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day6' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day7' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day8' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
   )
```

And when I run below

```
 WITH data AS (
              SELECT 'person1' person, 'day1' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day2' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day3' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day4' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day5' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day6' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day7' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day8' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
   )                     
    SELECT person, DAY, flag,
                 CASE WHEN flag = lag(flag) over (PARTITION BY person
                                                   ORDER BY DAY)
                       THEN 0
                       ELSE 1
                  END gap
             FROM DATA;
```

give me this output

```
person1 day1    Y   1
person1 day2    Y   0
person1 day3    Y   0
person1 day4    N   1
person1 day5    N   0
person1 day6    Y   1
person1 day7    Y   0
person1 day8    Y   0
```

Upto here I understand. Want to know when I add below part in above query

```
SELECT person, DAY, flag, SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person
                                            ORDER BY DAY) grp
```

Like this

```
WITH data AS (
              SELECT 'person1' person, 'day1' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day2' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day3' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day4' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day5' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day6' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day7' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day8' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
   )
   
   SELECT person, DAY, flag, SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person
                                            ORDER BY DAY) grp
   From
   ( SELECT person, DAY, flag,
                 CASE WHEN flag = lag(flag) over (PARTITION BY person
                                                   ORDER BY DAY)
                       THEN 0
                       ELSE 1
                  END gap
             FROM DATA) ;
```

How come its giving result like this ? Its doing `sum` over all partitions of `person1`, how value is being summed here ? Can anyone help me to understand here ? Not able to understand how the 4th column is derived.

```
person1 day1    Y   1
person1 day2    Y   1
person1 day3    Y   1
person1 day4    N   2
person1 day5    N   2
person1 day6    Y   3
person1 day7    Y   3
person1 day8    Y   3
```

Comment: . . What do you not understand?  It is using the functionality for a cumulative sum.  Do you not follow the syntax?  The logic for a cumulative sum?  Or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Increment value depending on changes in other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292723/sql-increment-value-depending-on-changes-in-other-columns)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to understand if we keep `gap` in the result.  I've updated the fiddle to include `gap` in the result.

This is a running sum (of the gap value) over all the rows up to this row in the partition, but in the order specified. Each row in the partition (base on the order) adds to the sum.

Here's a fiddle / test case, to show different ways to order sum, and the last example removes the `ORDER BY`.  Without the `ORDER BY` the sum is performed over all rows at once.

Test case:

[Test case with various examples of sum order](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dd5cffd553d27bbdad6028337fa8c71c)

`SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY DAY) grp`

[image]

`SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY DAY DESC) grp`

[image]

`SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person) grp`

[image]

Comment: am still not able to able to understand, how first 3 rows got one, 4th and 5th got 2 and last 3 got 3..? :(

Comment: @FreshTransistor Because `gap` was 1 on the first day of the partition, so the current rolling sum is 1 for that row, and all subsequent rows until the next non-0 gap (ordered by day).  Each non-0 `gap` adds to the sum as we roll through the rows (days) in the partition.

Comment: but how it does know that first three belongs to same group, 4-5 to 2nd group and 6-7-8 belongs to 3rd group ?

Comment: <<so the current rolling sum is 1 for that row>>  Cleared ,but << and all subsequent rows until the next non-0 gap (ordered by day) >> is not clear ? why one is assigned to 2nd and 3rd row ?

Comment: @FreshTransistor That's how `sum` behaves: (1) = 1; (1 + 0) = 1; (1 + 0 + 0) = 1; (1 + 0 + 0 + 1) = 2; ... based on the order of the day column.  `SUM` uses all the prior rows in the partition to determine the `SUM` of the current row.

Comment: so you mean, sum will only work from start to until the current row ..?

Comment: @FreshTransistor With the `ORDER BY` clause, yes.  Note the last example without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: when we add order, it stops on every record and sums all prior rows to current, but it sums all at once when there is no order...correct ?

Comment: @FreshTransistor Think of `ORDER BY` as determining the groups and order of operations within each partition.  Each row in the same group (day) is added to the overall sum at the same time.  Without `ORDER BY`, we treat all the rows in the partition as the same single group.

Comment: @FreshTransistor Please, chech the documentation for the [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056), especially the definition of the *window*. When you specify `order by` for the `sum`, it becomes a window function, and `order by day asc` implicitly implies window specification as `range between unbounded preceding and current row`, so all the rows in the window (from the beginning of the partition (`person` in your case) up to the current row) are aggregated with `sum`

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where each island is defined as being a cluster of records belonging to the same person and flag values, as ordered by the day column.  We can use the difference in row numbers method along with a few other tricks here.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY day) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person, flag ORDER BY day) rn2
    FROM data t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(day) OVER (PARTITION BY person, rn1 - rn2) min_day
    FROM cte t
)

SELECT person, day, flag, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY min_day) grp
FROM cte2
ORDER BY person, day;
```

### Demo

Note that rather than having a text `day` column with values like `day1`, `day2`, etc., it would be better to have an actual date or timestamp column there.  For the 9 records of sample data you did provide though, it happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [analytic functions documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

> If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

So your query is effectively:

```sql
WITH data AS (
              SELECT 'person1' person, 'day1' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day2' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day3' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day4' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day5' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day6' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day7' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day8' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
)
SELECT person,
       DAY,
       flag,
       SUM(gap) over (
         PARTITION BY person
         ORDER BY DAY
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS grp
From   (
  SELECT person,
         DAY,
         flag,
         CASE WHEN flag = lag(flag) over (
                            PARTITION BY person
                            ORDER BY DAY
                          )
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS gap
  FROM   DATA
);
```

This means that, for each row (for each `person` ordered by `day`), you are performing the `SUM` of the changes in the `flag` only over that day and all the preceding days.

So:

- When `day` is `day1` the the `SUM` is only over the change in flags for the `day1` row.
- When `day` is `day2` the the `SUM` is over the change in flags for the `day1` and `day2` rows.
- When `day` is `day3` the the `SUM` is over the change in flags for the `day1`, `day2` and `day3` rows.
- etc.

---

From Oracle 12, you can write the query in a simpler format using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
WITH data AS (
              SELECT 'person1' person, 'day1' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day2' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day3' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day4' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day5' day, 'N' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day6' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day7' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'person1' person, 'day8' day, 'Y' flag FROM dual
)
SELECT person,
       DAY,
       flag,
       grp
FROM   DATA
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY person
  ORDER BY day
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS grp
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (same_flags+)
  DEFINE same_flags AS FIRST(flag) = flag
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=348ba841be44fd674d58e7fdd159e302)*