# Generate row number based on group of number and increase the number if different digit appears

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We want to generate row number based on Series column order by Sequence column. For row 1 to 3, series is 1 hence those should be grouped as 1. On row 4, 0 appears and that is causing series to break hence grouping should change from there.

Data and output example:

[image: Group Number column is to populate]

Below is the code to generate the data.

```
        Select 1 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 2 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 3 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 4 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 5 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 6 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 7 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 8 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 9 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 10 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 11 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 12 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 13 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 14 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 15 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 16 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 17 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 18 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 19 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 20 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 21 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 22 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 23 AS Sequence,1 AS Series
```

Comment: You need to explain the goal/logic here... You tell us the results are wrong, but not why, what you expect, nor what the logic for your expectations are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Increment value depending on changes in other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292723/sql-increment-value-depending-on-changes-in-other-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL incrementing counter based on change in a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380595/t-sql-incrementing-counter-based-on-change-in-a-column-value/29382442)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LAG` window function in a subquery then use `SUM`
condition aggregate window function to make it.

```
;with cte as (
   Select 1 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 2 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 3 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 4 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 5 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 6 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 7 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 8 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 9 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 10 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 11 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 12 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 13 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 14 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 15 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 16 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 17 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 18 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 19 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 20 AS Sequence,0 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 21 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 22 AS Sequence,1 AS Series UNION ALL
Select 23 AS Sequence,1 AS Series 
)

SELECT  Sequence,Series,
       SUM(CASE WHEN n_Series <> Series THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY Sequence) + 1 generalNumber
FROM (
 SELECT *,LAG(Series) OVER( ORDER BY Sequence) n_Series
 FROM CTE
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a2db874ae24468a6db886234f8de139)