# SQL Server / Oracle: How to increase index column dependent on another column?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-update

Given the following table:

```
Column1 Column2 idx
-------------------
1       1       0
2       1       0
3       2       0
4       3       0
5       3       0
1       3       0
```

How could I increase the `idx` column dependent on `column2` in SQL Server and Oracle with an `UPDATE` statement?

I would like to have:

```
Column1 Column2 idx
--------------------
1       1       0
2       1       1
3       2       0
4       3       0
5       3       1
1       3       2
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What is the idx order, by column1? Can that have duplicates for the same column2 value (since you've shown it as not unique)? Do you really need to store that value, or just generate it when the table is queried (what happens if the row with column1=5 is deleted?) And why both database types - are you trying to find a single statement that works on both, or separate answers for each?

Comment: What is the logic to apply the `idx` column numbering? It apparently is not based on the sort order of `column1`, so what logic should be applied?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380595/t-sql-incrementing-counter-based-on-change-in-a-column-value

Comment: Ordering is not relevant in that case. I just want to have each Column2 value having one idx starting at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (or similar) approach should work for both:

```
;with x as (
  select idx, row_number() over(partition by Column2 order by Column1) as new_idx
  from tbl
)
update x set idx = new_idx
```

(Here I assume that there is a typo in 6th row for Column1 - if not, there should be something else for ordering)

Comment: Thanks. Works in SQL Server, not in Oracle though.

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle you need a MERGE statement for this:

```
merge into x using (
  select rowid as rid, 
         row_number() over(partition by Column2 order by Column1) as new_idx
  from tbl
) t on (t.rid = x.rowid)
when matched then 
  set idx = t.new_idx;
```

Instead of using `rowid` you can replace the join with the primary key columns of the table.