# T-SQL Statement OVER Clause Ranking Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Field1  Field2  ValidFrom
200     a       01.01.1999
200     b       01.01.2015
210     c       01.01.2015
210     c       01.01.2010
```

Now I try to generate a select-statement with an additional column, that increments when Field1 stays the same, but Field2 changes. The order of the value in the extraColumn should depend on the ValidFrom, which means e.g. 1 for 01.01.1999 and 2 for 01.01.2015 (and not the other way around!).
When Field1 changes, the value in the extraColumn should start with 1 again. It should keep the same value, when the combination of Field1 and Field2 doesn't change. 
So the result I'd like to have would look like this:

```
extraColumn Field1  Field2  ValidFrom
1           200     a       01.01.1999
2           200     b       01.01.2015
1           210     c       01.01.2015
1           210     c       01.01.2010
```

I tried to get this result by using this query with the RANK() function:

```
select RANK() OVER (
  PARTITION BY [Field1], [Field2] 
  ORDER BY [ValidFrom] DESC
) as 'extraColumn'
,Field1 ,Field2 ,ValidFrom
FROM table1
```

Unfortunately this did not work as I expected it to and it did kind of the opposite of which I wanted, so my result looked like:

```
extraColumn Field1  Field2  ValidFrom
1           200     a       01.01.1999
1           200     b       01.01.2015
1           210     c       01.01.2015
2           210     c       01.01.2010
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: In your example, the last two rows, neither Field1 nor Field 2 changed.

Comment: Right. And therefore I would like to have the same value in the extraColumn.

Comment: Can you explain this further ** that increments when the combination of Field1 and Field2 changes (the order should depend on ValidFrom) and gets set back to 1, when Field1 changes, so the result I'd like to have would look like this**

Comment: Is `ValidFrom` not a date? If so, why is the 2010 result being treated as if it comes somewhere other than between the 1999 and 2015 items?

Comment: Why is 3rd row back to 1 and not 3? Both Field1 and Field2 did change between rows 2 and 3?

Comment: @DVT I edited the question. Maybe it's better to understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382442/3925232) I have answered a similar problem. Below is the adaptation to your conditions:

```
-- Preparation
declare @t table (
  Field1 int,
  Field2 char,
  ValidFrom date
);

insert into @t (Field1, Field2, ValidFrom)
values
(200, 'a', '19990101'),
(200, 'b', '20150101'),
(210, 'c', '20150101'),
(210, 'c', '20100101');

-- The query
with cte as (
  select t.*,
    lag(t.Field2) over(partition by t.Field1 order by t.ValidFrom) as [Prev2]
  from @t t
)
select c.Field1, c.Field2, c.ValidFrom,
  sum(case when c.Prev2 = c.Field2 then 0 else 1 end)
  over(partition by c.Field1 order by c.ValidFrom) as [ExtraColumn]
from cte c;
```

I only hope you aren't going to run this against millions or records, because 2 partitionings won't make it easy on the CPU and memory. Oh yes, and you need SQL Server 2012 or later for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DENSE_RANK`, you need to use `Field2` in `order by`  to get the required result not `ValidFrom`

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Field1] ORDER BY [Field2])
```

Comment: Thanks! This already helped a lot, but unfortunately this way the value of the extraColumns doesn't depend on the ValidFrom.

Comment: @moons - I don't understand the need of `ValidFrom` here.. You cannot use `ValidFrom` here because the `dense_rank/rank` will not increment the number only when the order by column does not change .. `ValidFrom` has two different values for  `210` so if you use it you will not get the expected result

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. I did a mistake with my first query, because I'm new to this whole concept of the OVER Clause. But nevertheless, I need the values of the extraColumn to be in the same order as the ValidFrom. The same combination of field1 and field2 + a bigger ValidFrom should result in a bigger value in the extraColumn.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
WITH 
    cte_MaxDate AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            MaxDate = MAX(td.ValidFrom) OVER (PARTITION BY td.Feild1, td.Field2)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY md.Feild1 ORDER BY md.MaxDate, md.Field2),
    md.Feild1, md.Field2, md.ValidFrom--, md.MaxDate
FROM
    cte_MaxDate md;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use recursion here to calculate row-by-row whatever field2 changed or not.

```
WITH CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT  * 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY ValidFrom) RN
    FROM Table1
)
, RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, 1 AS ExtraColumn 
    FROM CTE_RN WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.*
    , CASE WHEN r.Field2 = c.Field2 THEN r.ExtraColumn ELSE r.ExtraColumn + 1 END
    FROM RCTE r 
    INNER JOIN CTE_RN c ON r.Field1 = c.Field1 AND r.RN + 1 = c.RN

)
SELECT * 
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY Field1, ValidFrom
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2c6f/1)
(I added few more rows for more complex sample)